# Is there a use for _tuple in Python?

Tags: python, namedtuple, python-internals

I read the official documentation of [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) today and found `_tuple` in the `__new__` method. I did not find where the `_tuple` was defined.

You can try running the code below in Python, it does not raise any error.

```
>>> Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'], verbose=True)
class Point(tuple):
    'Point(x, y)'

    __slots__ = ()

    _fields = ('x', 'y')

    def __new__(_cls, x, y):
        'Create a new instance of Point(x, y)'
        return _tuple.__new__(_cls, (x, y)) # Here. Why _tuple?
```

***Update:*** What are the advantages of

```
from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple
```

Is that just to let `tuple` be a *protected value*? Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the generic [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e831a98b3f43/Lib/collections/__init__.py#l266) (you can see the source code generated for this specific namedtuple by printing `Point._source`):

```
from builtins import property as _property, tuple as _tuple
```

So `_tuple` here is just an alias for the built-in `tuple` type:

```
In [1]: from builtins import tuple as _tuple

In [2]: tuple is _tuple
Out[2]: True
```

`collections.namedtuple` was added in Python 2.6.0. This was the initial source code for the `__new__` method:

```
def __new__(cls, %(argtxt)s):
    return tuple.__new__(cls, (%(argtxt)s)) \n
```

The thing is, the source code is in *string*. They later format it using `% locals()`. If `tuple` was listed in `argtxt`, then `tuple.__new__` would have called the `__new__` method of whatever the `tuple` field contained. In contrast, `_tuple` works as expected because `namedtuple` doesn't allow field names starting with `_`.

The bug was fixed in Python 2.6.3 release (see the [changelog](http://ftp.python.org/download/releases/2.6.3/NEWS.txt) - *collections.namedtuple() was not working with the following field names:  cls, self, tuple, itemgetter, and property*).

Comment: +1 This is a correct answer.  The \_tuple() was used so that users could create something like ``Args = namedtuple("Args", ["tuple", "dict"])``.  Supporting this behavior was important because the fieldnames may not be under the users control (i.e. headers in a CSV file).