# Namespacing issue in Python

Tags: python, namespaces

I am using a program where Python is the native scripting language.  Unfortunately, they have a native function that uses the name `bytes`. This causes a problem when I am trying to use the actual `bytes` built-in function, and it thinks I am referencing that built-in variable.  I will show you what I mean, one object as the following built-in code:

```
def receive(row, table, message, bytes):
     #This is defined in the GUI
```

So, `row`, `table`, `message`, and `bytes` are all passed in as arguments, effectively overwriting the name `bytes`.  So if I were to say `bytes(something).decode()` I get a  `TypeError: 'bytes' object is not callable`

Is there any way to get out of this jam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a different name for the fourth parameter (if you  can change the signature of the function)

```
def receive(row, table, message, bytes_):
    #This is defined in the GUI
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25337530/2301450) one. Just `from builtins import bytes as _bytes`; this will let you do `_bytes(something).decode()`.

Although renaming the fourth argument is a better solution.